# my outer div background extends when using negative margins in the child div

Tags: css, html, background-color, margin

Here is my stylesheet code

```
#topwrapper {
    background: url(images/orangebg.jpg) repeat-x top; 
    height: 502px;
}

#mainwrapper {
    background:url(images/bluebg.jpg) repeat;
}

#maincontent {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 961px; 
    background-color:#F0EFEF;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -312px;
}
```

I want the maincontent div to move up into the orange div but it is bringing the bluebg.jpg with it (cutting short the orangebg.jpg). When I tried using -top: 312px; instead of the negative margin it added space below the #maincontent.

The code on the page reads

```
<div id="topwrapper"></div>
<div id="mainwrapper"><div id="maincontent">test test</div></div>
```

View on jsfiddle
jsfiddle.net/bdh2a - remove the margin-top: -312px; and that is how I need the orange background to look with the grey box on top of it

Comment: Can you give us the html too? or better a jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? Or even better, put it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Yeah, we need to know how your html is organized.

Comment: i revised my question to include the code

Comment: why not move the maincontent div outside the mainwrapper div, so they are siblings and wont effect each other as much. It will be easier to position them separately.

Comment: I can't really picture what it is you are going for, maybe set up a jsfiddle.

Comment: The orange background is supposed to go behind the grey box for 312px but the blue background is stretching up with the grey box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Found a solution!!**

```
#topwrapper {
    background: url(images/orangebg.jpg) repeat-x top; 
    height: 502px;
}

#mainwrapper {
    background:url(images/bluebg.jpg) repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

#maincontent {
    width: 961px; 
    background-color:#F0EFEF;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -312px;
    margin-left: -480px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
}
```

The code on the page stays the same

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can set `margin-top: -312px;` to `mainwrapper` div?

Comment: Thats what its doing now which I don't want. Basically I have an orange background that is 512px and a blue background that stretches longer (don't know the height) and then a grey box on top of both. The grey box starts halfway through the orange background and continues over the blue background and then they both stretch together depending on how much info is in the grey box (different on each page). I can't make the blue background the body.

Comment: jsfiddle example would really help to understand your goal

Comment: @user1532405 all you have to do is replacing `margin-top` with `top` attribute, in this case margin-top causes the parent of that div also to go up

Comment: I tried that but it added alot of space below the box (because its positioned relative so the div automatically leaves space for it). I have a footer going across the page after the blue background so I can't have 312 extra pixels on the bottom of the page.

Comment: I updated jsfiddle to include the footer. Try changing the -margin to -top and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

## Re-arrange your html like this:

```
<div id="mainwrapper">
<div id="maincontent"><p>text text</p></div>  
<div id="topwrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Then use this CSS setup (adjusting the heights and stuff of course):

```
#mainwrapper{
height:100%;
background-color:#FF4200;
width:100%;
}

#topwrapper {
background-color:#1B00FF;
height:100px;
min-width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
position:absolute;
top:0;
z-index:0;
}

#maincontent {
margin: 0 auto;
padding:20px;
top:20px;
background-color:#ccc;
position: relative;
color:#000;
z-index:1;
width:80%
}
```

Check out this jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/imakeitpretty/yqnfk/
There is a lot of greek text in there because you can't see the orange expand without it. "text text" isn't enough to do it.

Comment: I need mainwrapper to have a blue background. I also need maincontent and mainwrapper to stretch together. How can i position maincontent to go on top of both topwrapper and mainwrapper

Comment: I revised my answer. See above.

Comment: where is the grey box? I still need the greybox? By making the background transparent there is no grey box

Comment: just change the background of maincontent to grey. I also gave the grey box a width. See the change above. I also update the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks! We are slowly getting there It works fine with your heights. For some reason when I switch it to the height that I need it, the blue disappears. The #topwrapper in my code has a height of 512px and the #maincontent starts at 312px from the top. In addition there is a 55px margin between the #maincontent and the bottom footer that needs the blue background